# Remove Show desktop button next to clock on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Using Windows 10 v1803. Is there any way to remove the thin `Show desktop` slice next to the clock? It is only 5 pixels wide (including the thin grey border), but it is annoying!

[image: Windows 10 Show Desktop slice]

The image on the left is the slice itself and the image on the right is what you see when you right-click the slice. Things I have tried so far:

- Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Performance > Settings. `Enable Peek` is off.
- Control Panel > Taskbar and Navigation. `Use Peek to preview the desktop when you move your mouse to the Show desktop button at the end of the taskbar` is `Off`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to remove the show-desktop slice using
the free app
[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)

To install with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `choco install 7-taskbar-tweaker`

Use the tweak called `Hide the “show desktop” button`:

[image]

Comment: Theoretically all this is doing is changing some registry value. It would be really nice to know what to change manually so that we don't have to run a whole app to do this

Comment: Yes, agreed. Have discovered you have to have `7+ Taskbar Tweaker` running for the changes to be active. Not ideal...the changes should be permanent.

Comment: Not everything is done via the registry. However, it's possible to use Process Explorer to trace the execution of 7+ Taskbar Tweaker.

Comment: @NoviceLinux-WindowsGeek What makes you claim there is a registry setting for this? Did you find keys analyzing Explorer internals or traced 7+ Taskbar Tweaker's activity?

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by the answer by ChrisB, here is an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script that hides the button:

```
Control, Hide, , TrayShowDesktopButtonWClass1, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
```

If using AutoHotkey v2, the syntax is:

```
ControlHide("TrayShowDesktopButtonWClass1", "ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
```

(To use: Install AutoHotkey, save this to a `.ahk` file and doubleclick it. You can also add a shortcut to the startup folder in the start menu to have it run automatically on login.)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like those precompiled closed-source tools so here is a simple [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script that you can copy in your startup folder:

```
$hwnd = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]", "")
ControlHide($hwnd, "", "TrayShowDesktopButtonWClass1")
```

Comment: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker is no longer (completely) closed source. https://github.com/m417z/7-Taskbar-Tweaker